# Image call from dB is iterating twice with PHP call

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing something relatively simple that I've done many times, and yet for some reason this is giving me grief.  I have the following to call the image from the db:

```
    $ViewQuery = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY last_name asc;";
    $Execute = mysqli_query($con, $ViewQuery);

    while($DataRows = mysqli_fetch_array($Execute)) {
        $profile_pic = $DataRows["profile_pic"];
?>
```

Then the following to call it to the front end.

```
<img src="../assets/images/profile_pics/<?php 
   echo htmlentities($profile_pic); 
?>" width="50px" height="50px">
<?php } ?>
```

The above is a simplified version, but basically I want all the profile picture to display in a table.  I have this exact same code for a similar page and it works fine; on this page I'm getting the following error in the `<img>` tag:

```
src="../assets/images/profile_pics/assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_emerald.png"
```

It's doing this for every image call...Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?  Like I said this code is elsewhere & works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: dump out  or watch$profile_pic in a debugger, should be your first step to debugging this..

Comment: You say it works "elsewhere" - is the base path the same in both places?  Otherwise, the relative reference "../assets..." would take it to a different place.

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  The file paths are correct and of course hard coded (which I did as a check) work fine.  The problem is that it's iterating ../assets/images/profile_pics twice.

Comment: I think ur calling your $Execute twice, from initialization and by fetching

Comment: I don't think so -  but willing to try anything I combined the first two statements and am getting the same result.  This is just weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that anyone gives a crap...well at least not as much as I do, but I tinkered with this for too long, so I'll answer my own question.

I had to change my call from this:

```
<img src="../assets/images/profile_pics/<?php echo htmlentities($profile_pic); ?>" width="50px" height="50px">
```

to this:

```
<img src="../<?php echo htmlentities($profile_pic); ?>" width="50px" height="50px">
```

Buggy weirdness...like I said identical code on another page in the same folder does not require and yet this page does.